# Axis2 with Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-axis

I"m starting to use Axis2, never worked with it before.

Maven was a dependency for Axis2 samples to work. I followed the steps correctly and have created the environment variables and restarted windows 7.

When trying to run any of the axis2 samples, I get this error message:

```
cd C:\Apache\axis\samples\java_first_jaxws; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02" C:\\Apache\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

ERROR: M2_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation
```

I have double checked the environment variables and they are correct. There is a thing that is bugging me. When I run `mvn --version` on command, it returns me `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` and this error is related to a POM file that doesn't exists. All samples from Axis2 have a pom.xml file.

Since it is my first contact with Java, I think it is a easy to solve problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Running this:
`cd /d C:\Apache\axis\samples\java_first_jaxws and then mvn install`

Result:
`[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "pom.xml". You must specify a valid lifecycle ph
ase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-
artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate
, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-res
ources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, g
enerate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-class
es, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post
-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-si
te, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhase
NotFoundException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are you using some kind of Cygwin shell or did you copy this from some webpage? The command you pasted is not valid if you use a plain old Command Prompt.
- Set `JAVA_HOME` in your environment variables, not on the command line.
- Add C:\Apache\maven\bin to your `PATH` environment variable so that you don't always have to run `mvn` by specifying the path to it.
- Set `M2_HOME` in your environment variables, I guess it should be C:\Apache\maven\bin.

Comment: I have JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME and M2_HOME\bin, all environment variables are OK according to the installation guide of Maven and Axis2. When you say " or did you copy this from some webpage" copied what?

Comment: @Gerep: If you run a command prompt and run `set`, do all variables show up? Also, I was talking about the command you posted (`cd <something>; "variable=something" mvn`) - that's an illegal expression for Windows shells, hence the whole "The syntax of the command is incorrect.")

Comment: about that  (`cd <something>; "variable=something" mvn`), it was generated by NetBeans7...and yes...the `set` command returns all variables necessary for the project to run...

Comment: @Gerep: now I see, it seems NetBeans is complicating things because it is generating Linux shell script. Can you start Command Prompt and run `cd /d C:\Apache\axis\samples\java_first_jaxws` and then `mvn install` ?

Comment: @Gerep: with regards to the update, did you run `mvn install pom.xml` or did you use NetBeans again? You should only run `mvn install` and Maven should find the POM by itself. You also didn't mention where you got that Maven download from, and what version it is.

Comment: no, I haven't used NetBeans, and I run mvn install...I downloaded Maven maven.apache.org, the version Maven 3.0.4

Answer (score 2):

I saw this error message with Maven 3.0 in Windows XP. For me, I saw the error when I surround the `M2_HOME` variable with quotes.

```
M2_HOME="C:\..."
```

But the error disappeared when I removed the quotes.

```
M2_HOME=C:\...
```

I didn't need the quotes because the path had no spaces in it. It's possible that the quotes are needed when there are spaces present in the path, but I didn't test this.

And FYI I debugged the problem by removing the `@echo off` directive from the start of `mvn.bat`. The problem seemed to occur when the `M2_HOME` variable was referenced inside another pair of quotes.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. The amount of configuration crap required for installation is unbelievable. What ever happened to double click and install.